# Replace a char in django template before final rendering

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, django-bootstrap4

I want to make all of my asterisks (*) in a template in red color in a Django Template. (E.g. in form labels that * symbol points the field is required. But when  putting * in label of a form field it is rendered as black color as usual.

How can I accomplish this by for example registering a filter or tag?

Note that I use some libraries (e.g. bootstrap4 form) and the page is full of {{ }} tags. BUT I want to find&replace all ;black *' with 'red *' in final rendered html page.

**EDIT**: I use django-bootstrap4 and so I simply use 
`{% bootstrap_form form %}` in my templates. (So not have explicit access to label texts) How can I perform my goal?

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me

```
# templatetags/custom_tags.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def mark_as_required(text):
    return '<span style="color:red">{text}</span>'.format(text=text)
```

```
# templates/xxx.html
...
{% load custom_tags %}
...
{{ '*'|mark_as_required|safe }}
...
```

Comment: Thank you. But please see my EDIT. Thanks

Comment: It's better you add django-bootstrap tag too, to your question